# I need a extremely small display for a chip computer

Tags: hdmi, mini-pc, vga

I would like to build an extremely small, portable computer and need a screen 3.5 inches across or less that connects by either VGA, HDMI, or composite. I would also like it to be under 40 dollars, but I would take slightly more expensive. I am going to be connecting this to a Chip computer. I do not care too much about how good the display quality is. I just need to be able to see things on it and it to be functional. I have been looking everywhere for this, but the only ones I can find are for raspberry pie and do not have the right connection type.

Comment: It seems likely that you have not done much research on your own before posting this question.  There are multiple mini displays such as you are looking for.  A simple search on Amazon will yield good results.  Please exhaust all google and amazon searches before asking others to search for you.

Comment: @NZKshatriya The point of this site is to get recommendations. How is it helpful to say just search on Amazon? This is a good question, with specific requirements, why downvote it.

Comment: @vclaw  the point of this site is to help people yes, but people also need to help themselves first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this one for $24](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-5-inch-HDMI-LCD-TFT-Touchscreen-Display-1920-1080-for-Raspberry-pi-2-and-Pi/32774253132.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.174.WKwyJA&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10000073_10065_10068_10000074_10000132_10000033_10000030_119_10000167_10000026_10000175_10000126_10000129_10000023_10000123_432_10000069_10000068_10060_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10000063_301_10059_10000120_10099_10000020_10000156_10000158_10000013_10000117_10103_10102_10000016_10000114_10096_10000111_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10050_10107_10051_10106_10000097_10000094_10000090_10000147_10000091_10000144_10084_10000150_10000101_10083_10000100_10119_10080_10000153_10000104_10082_10000045_10081_10110_10000108_10111_10000191_10112_10113_10000197_10114_10000089_10000086_10037_10000179_10000083_10000042_10000135_10000080_10078_10079_10077_10000039_10073_10000140_10070_10000036_10122_10123_10120_10126_10124_10000187-10120,searchweb201603_9,afswitch_1_afChannel,ppcSwitch_5,single_sort_2_default&btsid=250d8bbf-ad0d-48a4-a414-e0eea2c5f33a&algo_expid=f1704ffa-5f4d-4ba1-992a-47c6d79325dc-20&algo_pvid=f1704ffa-5f4d-4ba1-992a-47c6d79325dc) HDMI Port, don't use Touch Pins, just connect it to power and HDMI port.
[image]

PAL/NTFS around $20 [check this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045IIZKU)
[image]

Or [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/8-LCD-4-3-Color-Monitor-IPS-HD-Screen-Display-VGA-BNC-AV-HDMI-Input-for-PC-CCTV-/262852424741?hash=item3d3339b425:g:y8UAAOSwCGVX2KHA) 48$ with VGA-HDMI-PAL/NTFS Port
[image]